# Getting WorkbookPart from row

Tags: openxml, openxml-sdk

I am writing and extension for OpenXML like shown in the sample. I would like to avoid having to pass the WorkbookPart as parameter. Is there any way to get the WorkbookPart directly from the row?

```
public static string GetCellTextValue(this Row row, WorkbookPart workbookPart, string column)
{            
    var cells = row.Elements<Cell>();
    var cell = cells.Where(p => p.CellReference == column + row.RowIndex.ToString()).FirstOrDefault();

    if (cell.DataType != null)
    {
        if (cell.DataType == CellValues.SharedString)
        {
            int id = -1;

            if (Int32.TryParse(cell.InnerText, out id))
            {
                SharedStringItem item = workbookPart.SharedStringTablePart.SharedStringTable.Elements<SharedStringItem>().ElementAt(id);

                if (item.Text != null)
                {
                    return item.Text.Text;
                }
                else if (item.InnerText != null)
                {
                    return item.InnerText;
                }
                else if (item.InnerXml != null)
                {
                    return item.InnerXml;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return string.Empty;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, none of the strongly-typed classes of the Open XML SDK (e.g., `Workbook`, `Worksheet`, `Row`) have properties pointing back to the `OpenXmlPart` (e.g., `WorkbookPart`, `WorksheetPart`) in which they are contained or any other part related to their immediate container. Unless you amend your API in other ways, you will have to pass that `WorkbookPart`.